# Java: Style issue for if statement returns?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, return

Say that I had a method that required me to loop through a data structure, then return a number stored in a particular index if it was equal to a given number. If two numbers in the data structure were equal, then it would return the number that came first.

```
public static int method(int value, List<Integer> list){
    for (Integer i: list){
        if (i == value){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a problematic solution, because the method may not necessarily return. I suppose you could create a variable to store a reference to the equivalent value and return that, so the compiler does not issue a error about the lack of a return statement, but that would be pointless code.

Is there a better way to do this? Would you just return 0, or return null, in the case that you are returning an object?

Comment: @LawrenceDol. The OP states that very point in the question "*This is a problematic solution, because the method may not necessarily return*".

Comment: How about changing the signature to public static Optional<Integer> (int, value, List<Integer> list)

Comment: @beresfordt: I assume the code is purely exemplary, not actual (but, who knows, these days).

Comment: Yeah, I realised that seconds after posting my previous comment, so deleted it

Comment: Yeah this is not actual code that I'm using. It's just a theoretical question.

Comment: @user3450277.  Did any of the answers below help? If so please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not finding the value is expected and normal, return -1 to indicate "not found", since the normal return is an array index.

However, if running the loop to completion is truly abnormal and unexpected, then throw an exception, don't return a magic value.

```
 public static int method(int value, List<Integer> list){
    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        Integer i = list.get(j);
        if (i == value){
            return j;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("The method 'SomeClass.method' reach an invalid termination point");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this is a theoretical question, otherwise you would really just return `true` (it is in the list) or `false` (it is not in the list). You already know the number you are searching for, so finding it and returning it adds no value to the calling code. In fact, for this case, you would just use [`public boolean contains(O o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) from [`List`s implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) of `Collection` and avoid writing your own method.

```
public static boolean method(int value, List<Integer> list) {
    for (Integer i: list)
        if (i == value) return true;
    return false;
}
```

So given this academic question, why not return the *index* of the number in the list that you want, and return `-1` if no number in the list matches the one you want.

```
 public static int method(int value, List<Integer> list) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        Integer i = list.get(j);
        if (i == value){
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This way you don't have to define a "special case" return value, do autoboxing to return `null`, or define a new construct to carry both the number and a "success" flag.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Collection.contains()` and `List.indexOf()`. The way they handle both cases is very idiomatic for Java and will be immediately familiar to Java developers.